# Typehint for subclasses in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, python-typing

I am trying to do an orderly job with my type hints to have a code that is easier to add to.

I have made the following classes:

```py
class Player(ABC)
    @abstractmethod
    def some_function():
        pass

class SomeSubclass(Player):
    def some_function():
        #some meaningfull code
        pass

p1: Type[Player] = SomeSubclass()
```

In the last line I get an expected type error by PyCharm:

> Expected Type 'Type[Player]' got 'SomeSubclass' instead

Do I use the wrong Typehint or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `Type` if the variable is expected to be an instance and not a class. Any of these should work:

```
p1: Player = SomeSubclass()
```

Or

```
p1: SomeSubclass = SomeSubclass()
```

Alternatively if you wanted `p1` to be a class and not an instance:

```
p1: Type[Player] = SomeSubclass
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use the `Type[X]` type declaration if you're typing a type (this is not a common situation -- an example might be if you had a factory function which takes a type, rather than an object instance, as its argument).  To type an object, just use the type of the object:

```
p1: Player = SomeSubclass()
```

Note that even with no type hint, mypy is going to automatically infer that `p1` is of type `SomeSubclass` and is therefore a `Player`.  You only need to add the `Player` type hint if you want to explicitly downgrade `p1` to a more general type so that you can assign a different subclass to it later.